# Count and show duplicate data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to count and show how much data are covered in each array.
At first, I filtered and set only the label which is not duplicated. And then I counted each as array. But it wouldn't work...

```
dataArray = ["a", "a", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "vgvg"]

const [count, setCounts] = useState<any[]>([])
const [labels, setLabels] = useState<any[]>([])

useEffect(() => {
  let b = dataArray.filter((x, i, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(x) === i
  })
  setLabels(b)
  console.log(label)
  // ["a", "bs", "vgvg"]

}, [dataArray]) 

useEffect(() => {
  let c = [] as any[]
  dataArray.map((data) => {
    c[data] = (c[data] || 0) + 1
  })
  setCounts(c)
  console.log(count)
  // {"a": 2, "bs": 4, "vgvg": 1}
}, [dataArray])


return (
  {labels.map((label, idx) => (
   <div>{label}: {counts[label]}</div>
  ))}
)
```

*error*

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like `Array.prototype.reduce` for this.

You could:

```
const TestComponent = ({ dataArray }) => {
    // Memoise the counts so it doesn't need to be calculated on each render.
    const counts = useMemo(() => {
        // use array reduce to calculate counts.
        return dataArray.reduce(
            (state, item) => {
                // if property does not yet exist add it and set to 0 count.
                if (state[item] === undefined) {
                    state[item] = 0;
                }

                // increment count
                state[item]++;

                // return updated state
                return state;
            }, 
            {} //initial state
        );
    }, [dataArray]);

    return (
        {
            
            Object
                // Use Object.keys to get an array of property names
                .keys(counts)
                // Map property names to desired view (label / count)
                .map((key) => (
                    <div
                        key={key}
                    >
                        {key}: counts[key]
                    </div>
                ))
        }
    )
}
```

The example reduce function given a `dataArray` of:

```
const dataArray = ["a", "a", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "vgvg"]
```

Would reduce to:

```
const result = {
    a: 2,
    bs: 4,
    vgvg: 1
}
```